# How to give values with array of objects as input to a step function input?

Tags: json, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-step-functions, state-machine-workflow

I have a step function output in the below format:
[{
"status" : "VALIDATION_FAILED",
"memberData":{
"metaData" : {
"fileId" : 101,
"FileName" : "abc.txt"
}
}
}]

Now I only want to give metaData as input to the next step in my step function.
Usually we access the data by using inputPath: $.status and so on. But I suspect, due to the presence of [ ], it's giving me an error of
' Invalid path '$.status' : Property ['status'] not found in path $.

I m unable to access any variable inside for the same reason. Can anyone please guide on how do I address this?

I came across some solutions but didn't get what I m looking for

Answer (score 1):

A filter expression similar to the following can be used given the output above:

`$[0].memberData.metaData`

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html